# Connecting Arduino Uno's TX pin directly to Esp8266 esp-01

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am new to esp8266 esp-01 and trying to figure out how to use it, in many tutorials on internet, I have seen people have connected Arduino uno's TX pin directly to esp8266 esp-01 without any voltage divider, we know that Arduino TX pin uses 5v, so isn't that will kill the esp-01 which is not 5v tolerant ?

Comment: There is still no definitive answer to this from Espressif. Anecdotal evidence says that the ESP8266 is 5V tolerant. The (current) datasheet does not say if it is or not. An early version may have said that it is. No one really knows.

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2016/07/28/ask-hackaday-is-the-esp8266-5v-tolerant/

Comment: Do it the correct way, use a logic level converter, they are inexpensive and you generally have less connections by the time everything is finished..

Answer (score -1):

Esp01 is not 5v tolerant so it could corrupt it at any time so don't do this and use voltage divider.